# Detecting client hangup in MIO

Tags: rust, mio

When using MIO (0.3.5) how do I detect the termination of a connection?

I tried the following:

```
extern crate mio;
use mio::{EventLoop,Token,ReadHint};
use std::io::Read;

fn main(){
  let listener = mio::tcp::TcpListener::bind("localhost:1234").unwrap();
  let (stream,_) : (mio::tcp::TcpStream, _)  =  listener.accept().unwrap();

  let mut event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
  event_loop.register(&stream,Token(0)).unwrap();
  println!("run...");
  event_loop.run(&mut H{stream:stream}).unwrap();
}

struct H{stream : mio::tcp::TcpStream}

impl mio::Handler for H{
  type Timeout = ();
  type Message = ();

  fn readable(&mut self, _ : &mut EventLoop<Self>, _ : Token, hint: ReadHint){
    let mut buf: [u8; 500] = [0; 500];
    println!("{} {}",(hint==ReadHint::data()),self.stream.read(&mut buf).unwrap());
    std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

Run this. Connect to it using something like `nc localhost 1234`. Terminate connection by using Ctrl-C. My code will think there is new data available (`hint==ReadHint::data()`). A try to read it will result in zero bytes available.

Shouldn't the hint be something like `ReadHint::hup()`?

Comment: Note: Rust indent style is 4 spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default when calling `register` on mio v0.3.5 is to register only for the `readable` [Interest](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/v0.3.x/mio/struct.Interest.html), so that is the only hint you will get.

If you want to be warned for hup as well, you need to use the function [register_opt](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/v0.3.x/mio/struct.EventLoop.html#method.register_opt) and give your `Interest` and `PollOpt` as parameters, so your code becomes:

```
extern crate mio;
use mio::{EventLoop,Token,ReadHint,PollOpt,Interest};
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let listener = mio::tcp::TcpListener::bind("localhost:1234").unwrap();
    let (stream,_) : (mio::tcp::TcpStream, _)  =  listener.accept().unwrap();

    let mut event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    let interest = Interest::readable() | Interest::hup();
    event_loop.register_opt(&stream,Token(0), interest,PollOpt::level()).unwrap();
    println!("run...");
    event_loop.run(&mut H{stream:stream}).unwrap();
}

struct H{stream : mio::tcp::TcpStream}

impl mio::Handler for H {
    type Timeout = ();
    type Message = ();

    fn readable(&mut self, event_loop : &mut EventLoop<Self>, _ : Token, hint: ReadHint){
        let mut buf: [u8; 500] = [0; 500];
        if hint.is_hup() {
            println!("Recieved hup, exiting");
            event_loop.shutdown();
            return;
        }
        println!("{} {}",hint.is_data(),self.stream.read(&mut buf).unwrap());
        std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

I think the default for the convenience function `register` has changed in v0.4.0 to be `Interest::all()` so this shouldn't be a problem in the future.