# How can I detect that the client has closed the socket using mio 0.6?

Tags: sockets, rust, mio

I want a way to detect that the client has closed the socket so I can `deregister` it, but I can not find any suitable way to do it.

My question is similar to [Detecting client hangup in MIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759271/detecting-client-hangup-in-mio), but there are two main differences:

1. I need a cross-platform solution. According to the source code of mio 0.6, `hup` is a UNIX-only thing, my code should also work on Windows.
2. The API of mio dramatically changed since 0.3.

Comment: If the client closed the socket, i.e. closed the connection normally, you will get a normal end of stream indication when reading, or a 'broken pipe' or 'connection reset' when writing.